# Getting error while converting rows to comma separated list using FOR XML

Tags: sql-server

Consider a database table holding Multiple rows and COlumns:
Group by salesid

```
salesid mrp sku    type 
1        20  58pl   pending
1        25  58po   Delivered
2        70  32pf   Dispatched
3        85  24jh   Pendig
2        58  32pg   Delivered
```

what i want :

```
salesid mrp    sku        type
1       20,25  58pl,58po  Pendig,Delivered
2       70,58  32pf,32pg  Dispatched,Delivered
3       85     24jh       Pendig
```

i am using Visual Studio 2017 C# and DataBase MSSQL 2017

what i tried :

```
 select distinct p.[salesid],
  STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + t1.type
         from payment_trans t1
         where p.[salesid] = t1.[salesid]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,2,'') type

        ,
  STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + t2.Merchant_SKU
         from payment_trans t2
         where p.[salesid] = t2.[salesid]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,2,'') sku 
        ,
  STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + t3.stockupId
         from payment_trans t3
         where p.[salesid] = t3.[salesid]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,2,'') stockupid 
        from payment_trans p where p.stockupId!=-1
```

its giving me an error : (SQL Error (245): Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ', ' to data type int. )
when i seprate integer value

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either t1.type,  t2.Merchant_SKU or t3.stockupId is an integer and needs to be casted to varchar before concatenating them.

Or just separate ', ' and the columns with "," and let the FOR XML perform the conversion.

Comment: t3.stockupId is an integer value.